# How to display text only once per item iterated in React map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I am trying to display text only once per iteration block, but it keeps displaying depending on how many indexed there are iterated.

How can I explain only once?

This is my code:

```
someArr.map((col, i) => {
  return (
    <div
      key={i}
    >
      {text} // should be displayed only ONCE
      {someRule === someOtherRule && (
        <Icon/>
      )}
   </div>
 )
})
```

So what happens here is that `Icon` and all other items get displayed correctly, but `{text}` gets displayed depending on how many there are iterations. How can I display it only once, regardless of iteration count?

Comment: I think it will be better if you can get this out of the map iterating if I understand thats right, its kinda as a header right?

Comment: Please provide an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check for the first index

```
  {i === 0 ? text: ''}
```